# How Can I make a Fluid Simulation liquid become gooey or viscous?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I would like to change the properties of a fluid sim so that the liquid behaves gooey viscous. Which parameters would I have to change to get a slow, gooey viscous fluid. Much like hot sugar candy (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEqvwnlMRvA).

I looked at some of the tutorials describing how to do honey, but they still look like water.

Also maybe there is an addon that does excatly that. I also would like to displace the mesh that results of this simulation by twisting it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primarily you want to adjust the [viscosity settings](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/fluid/types/domain.html#domain-world). The smaller the viscosity the more watery the simulation. Note that the exponent value is negated so increasing the exponent makes the final value smaller.

You will also find that the real world size makes a difference. A real world size of 10.0 will give a watery result while a real world size of 0.2 will be closer to a slushy with the same viscosity.

As for twisting the result, it will depend on the effect you want. You could use a [simple deform modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/simple_deform.html) or a [lattice deform](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/lattice.html). With a thick fluid sim you may also be able to use a collision object that spins around.