# How can I model something that behaves like molasses?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, mesh

I need to create a candy with a filling that is like jam or molasses, and make a render of one candy half eaten with the inside spilling out.

While modeling the candy itself and creating texture and material wasn't too difficult thanks to many resources found online, I'm at a loss as to how I could create the molasses-like inside and make the spill look natural.

Is there a way to model it via the use of soft body or particles or something alike, or would I need to model or sculpt it?

I use Cycles on Blender 2.79b.

Comment: Relevant: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79683/simulate-a-sticky-fluid-in-blender

Comment: A fluid sim with high viscosity would be the way to start, as mentioned in the above link, though, there is no support for stickiness

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48669/how-can-i-make-a-fluid-simulation-liquid-become-gooey-or-viscous

Comment: quick tutorial for liquid chocolate https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4jwlgtTNt8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a still image, many tools can be used: an experienced 3D artist will probably use just mesh editing or sculpting. Someone would use particles and meta objects. I would personally go with a two step approach: **fluid simulation first** to get an overall realistic shape, **then sculpting**, mostly to smooth it well and make it look nice.

#### TL;DR

The very short answer if you're going down the "Fluid simulation" route is: **a low "*Exponent*"** (1 - 2) in the *Fluid > Domain > Viscosity* settings **makes a thick fluid**.

---

#### Step by step example

1. **Scale**. Make sure your existing objects (empty candy and plane) have the dimensions of a few decimeters = ~0.1 to 0.5 Blender units in v2.79b (it's not important that they are exactly real-size, **EDIT: and actually if they are too small the fluid simulation could not work at all**, but they shouldn't be 1 unit long either, i.e. 1 meter). Resize them, then apply their scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).
2. **Set up a Fluid simulation**. Like this:

   1. a *Fluid*-type ball inside the cavity
   2. your existing candy as *Obstacle*
   3. a non-slip *Domain* cube with its bottom face corresponding to your standing surface. Reduce *Exponent* in viscosity to 1 or 2
   4. set the *Final* resolution to a medium value (e.g. 120) and the *Viewport Display* to *Final*, and reduce the Scene's *End* time to something like 80. You don't need 250 frames for this!

   [image]
3. ***Bake*** the fluid cache. Then choose a frame that you like, go to the *Modifier* tab and ***Apply* the *Fluidism*** modifier

   [image]
4. **Sculpt**. I would mostly use the ***Smooth* brush**, and a bit of *Inflate* and *Grab* to add variation

   [image]
5. **Shading**. Give it a specular, smooth, transparent, translucent material.

   [image]

   (I've also added some volume-emitted particles as bubbles, with a transparent, IOR<1 material)

Comment: Baking does absolutely nothing. I do have a load of files in the cache folder, bobj.gz and stuff, but I don't see any change on screen when I try to play the simulation.

Comment: I've added the blend to my question. I followed your instructions: set up a fluid, obstacle and domain.

Comment: Ok, found the problem. It was my fault! I'll edit my answer. However you should still set "Viewport Display" to "Final" in the domain